# How to prevent Bootstrap Modals from appearing in browser history?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Consider this scenario**

A user visits Page A, proceeds to Page B, clicks a link that launches a modal (code below)

```
<a href="mycontent.html" data-target="#modal_xl" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static">Click me</a>
```

Completes a form, submits the form, modal closes, Page B is reloaded.

**The problem**

In Firefox if the user presses the back button they are taken to Page A (expected behaviour at face value).  Browser History is Page B -> Page A

In Chrome and Safari, however, when the user presses the back button they are taken to Page B again.  Browser History is Page B -> Page B -> Page A.

It seems as though in Chrome and Safari the modal/page reload is registering as another page visit on Page B.  If this form is submitted 4 or 5 times then the user must press the back button 4 or 5 times to get to what they would be expecting to be the previous page.

**Half a solution**

I have attached the following code to page B for when the page reloads

```
if(document.referrer == window.location.href) {
    window.history.back();
}
```

This works for Chrome and Safari in that it takes the user back one step in the history meaning when they press the back button they go back to Page A.  However in Firefox it sends the user back to Page A because Firefox hasn't registered the modal as a second/separate page visit which isn't desired.

Building in browser detection is one way to fix the firefox problem but its a bit dirty/hacky and it this method does also activate the browser "forward history".

Is there a way to prevent the modal from adding browser history?

Comment: doesn't make sense in the first place that you have a modal bound to `<a>` with a valid href. A modal doesn't create history by itself unless you have some sort of pushstate code acting on it too or are using some sort of plugin or framework for single page app. Defintely seems like there is some missing information here

Comment: Sorry, but i can not reproduce this behavior in chrome. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z3w5byb/). If you are looking at this post whit in chrome, click the fiddle link, open the modal in the fiddle several times, then hit the browser back button and you will be redirected to this post, even though after each modal close a page reload takes place. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, it is surly not the modal which will lead to the page reload, but the form submit does. The `href` in the `a` of the modal button could just be remote modal content, we don't know, but that should still not be the problem. The problem i have is, that i can not reproduce the effect.

Comment: @DavidDomain Correct the `href` is loading remote modal content which includes the form.  I don't think the issue is the reload being triggered (btw your fiddle worked ok).  I think the problem is linked to the form submission. Perhaps when the form is posted it calls the controller which on success then redirects to `header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  The reason I'm suggesting the modal has something to do with it is the problem only occurs with the modals not with forms that are attached to a regular page.

Comment: @nikmav Could you try to load the form with an inline modal, no remote content  and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

if you are not going to submit some data like image or file, you can consider
using ajax to submit your data. so in any browser you history is Page A -> Page B.